# Why does my linux box make ARP requests for ip addresses outside its subnet?

Tags: linux-networking

My linux server is a VM with 1 nic attached (with ip `192.168.20.43`) as observed using the `ip a` command:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:f5:e5:67 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.20.43/24 brd 192.168.20.255 scope global noprefixroute enp1s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::5054:ff:fef5:e567/64 scope link noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Its default gateway is `192.168.20.254` as observed by the `ip route` command:

```
default via 192.168.20.254 dev enp1s0 proto static metric 100
192.168.20.0/24 dev enp1s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.20.43 metric 100
```

We can also see from the above that the netmask is a reasonable 24 bits.

From this we can see that the IPv4 address `192.168.30.66` is *outside* the defined subnet and thus only reachable via the default gateway.

Why then can I use `tcpdump` on `enp1s0` and observe arp requests from `192.168.20.43` for `192.168.30.66` when requesting traffic from `192.168.30.66`?

The tcpdump command is `tcpdump -nnni enp1s0 host 192.168.30.66` and we observe:

```
11:54:53.130897 IP 192.168.30.66.443 > 192.168.20.43.40862: Flags [.], seq 12922:14320, ack 917, win 227, options [nop,nop,TS val 3119187172 ecr 2528097971], length 1398
11:54:53.131013 IP 192.168.20.43.40862 > 192.168.30.66.443: Flags [.], ack 37962, win 835, options [nop,nop,TS val 2528101021 ecr 3119184135,nop,nop,sack 1 {12922:14320}], length 0
11:54:55.247778 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.30.66 tell 192.168.20.43, length 28
11:54:55.248505 ARP, Reply 192.168.30.66 is-at e0:db:55:70:db:75, length 46
```

I was under the impression that no ARP request should be made for IP addresses outside the subnet, regardless of the fact that both subnets are on the same layer2 ethernet segment (which is why a reply happens).

Comment: I don't think so. 192.168.20.43 already knows that 192.168.30.66 is local due to the existing session. I wouldn't expect an ARP request to *update* the cache to be sent to the router in that case.

Comment: Apologies @GregAskew but I don't understand how 192.168.20.43 knows 192.168.20.43 "is local". If I clear the arp tables of both systems, I can put a tcpdump on the router 192.168.20.254 and I can see 192.168.20.43 and 192.168.30.66 communicating via the router, until the ARP request/reply occurs, at which point the router is taken out of the path. The router not seeing the traffic after layer 2 delivery takes over makes sense, but why did the ARP update/request occur in the first place?

Comment: That sounds like the expected behavior to me. Unless Linux is "special".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause is the router. But **OP's *tcpdump*'s filter missed the relevant packet to capture: an ICMP redirect** from the router telling each host that it can reach directly the other host.

Because the router is a one-armed router which has both IP LANs 192.168.20.0/24 and 192.168.30.0/24 on the same interface and thus same Ethernet broadcast domain, it correctly deduces that an IPv4 communication from an host using 192.168.20.0/24 to a peer using 192.168.30.0/24 can be done directly and doesn't need the router to work.

Considering a Linux router configured like this:

```
# ip route
default via 192.0.2.1 dev wan0 metric 100 
192.0.2.0/24 dev wan0 proto kernel scope link src 192.0.2.2 metric 100 
192.168.20.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.20.254 metric 100 
192.168.30.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.30.254 metric 100
```

when such communication does happen between the two hosts through the router, it sends, possibly at a lazy rate, an ICMP redirect like these:

```
17:35:35.317159 IP 192.168.30.254 > 192.168.30.66: ICMP redirect 192.168.20.43 to host 192.168.20.43, length 92

17:35:36.329965 IP 192.168.20.254 > 192.168.20.43: ICMP redirect 192.168.30.66 to host 192.168.30.66, length 92
```

When the peers receive such information, they will (lazily, maybe once that multiple ICMP redirects were received) install a temporary route cache to override the normal route (even if normal routing cache has disappeared in Linux 3.6, special purpose routing cache such as redirects or PMTUD-related routes still exist). This can be found like this (running it on the 192.168.20.43 host *after* having received several ICMP redirect):

```
# ip route show cache
192.168.30.66 via 192.168.30.66 dev eth0 
    cache <redirected> expires 296sec
```

Then it's just following this route, triggering an ARP request to 192.168.30.66 in order to reach this host.

Comment: Agreed! This can be seen with a ping (and I assume a correctly setup tcpdump):
From 192.168.20.254: icmp_seq=2 Redirect Host(New nexthop: 192.168.30.66)